# iPhone App upload

Tags: iphone, upload

I'm uploading iPhone eBooks on itunesconnect.

This is my problem: Recently Apple requires the Bundle Name, Bundle Display Name and Product Name to be set to Author: Title.

there is a technical problem:
- the Bundle Name cannot contain spaces
- this can be solved by changing the Bundle Identifier using a conversion like rfc1034
example: `de.randomhouse.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`

but now there is a naming problem:
- if I change the bundle identifier with Apps I have uploaded before and want to upload again after a bugfix, the uplaod is not possible: a change of the bundle identifier is not allowed

this problem could be solved if I could
- either change the bundle identifier
- or if I could delete the rejected books from the App Store, so that I could upload it completely again

Can anyone help me?

Kind Regards,
Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to base the Bundle Identifier on the product name. If you have to change the product name, you can keep the old Bundle Identifier by hard-coding it.

For example:

Imagine you have an app called "Crime" with Bundle Identifier in your Info.plist of `de.randomhouse.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`. That identifier expands to `de.randomhouse.Crime`. Now, you must change the product name to "Ivine Welsh : Crime". You can keep the same bundle identifier by changing the entry in your Info.plist to `de.randomhouse.Crime`. The identifier is now independent of the product name.